# DataGrid deferred scrolling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, deferred

how to enable deferred scrolling on DataGrid control? There are corresponding properties in ListBox, ListView, etc, but seems that such property for DataGrid simply does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in XAML (Attached property)

```
ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Is the datagrid wrapped by a scrollviewer?  A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: I figured it out. What you need will look something like:
`<DataGrid ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">`

Comment: @Drewmate that's exactly what is written in answer, or i don't understand something?

Comment: I just didn't understand it at first.  And it wouldn't let me edit my first comment, so I added a second comment for people like me who need it spelled out exactly.